# How can I switch to the iframe using Selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I've used Selenium for a number projects without problems. This one, however, no dice.

I'm trying to automate a check out process, and sometimes there is a prompt to re-input information. The window has a javascript popup (I think), and, while I can select the `<div id="app">` portion without any problems, I CANNOT get find the `iframe` and focus on it.

So, this works:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id('app')
```

But, nothing works to recognize the frame and switch to it. For example, none these work:

```
driver.find_element_by_id()
driver.find_element_by_name()
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

And, I assume that because I can't find and switch to the iframe.

Help?

[image: webpage code]

Comment: Everyone, thank you for the quick and (I anticipate) helpful answers. I won't be able to test this out until later tonight or tomorrow. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with the text as *E-Mail Login* is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.zoid-visible[title='ec_payment'][name^='__zoid__ec__payment']")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='zoid-visible' and @title='ec_payment'][starts-with(@name, '__zoid__ec__payment')]")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: DebanjanB, thank you! This got me through it!

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_elem)
```

or

```
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe_id)
```

in your case you can use :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"));
```

to switch back to main use:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to switch to frame

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "zoid-ec-payment")]/iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```